# Python 3.1 Installation missing Tkinter on OS 10.6.4

Tags: python

Has anyone else had this problem? I have re-installed twice with the same result. The pre-install of 2.6 on the Mac had a lib-tk folder with the correct modules. Nothing like this is being created for 3.1. There is a Tkinter folder but it contains only a few obscure modules. Importing _tkinter and tkinter works but not Tkinter and all of the example programs fail.

Comment: What are you using to install? I just checked macports and noticed that the port `python31` does have a `no_tkinter` option (although this doesn't seem to be the default) - is it possible you're DLing or installing a version intended to not have tkinter accidentally?

Answer (score 1):

`Tkinter` was substantially refactored in Python 3 from a set of modules into packages. `Tkinter` is now `tkinter` and the `lib-tk` folder no longer exists.  At least some of the example tkinter programs included in the OS X 3.1 distribution work if you ensure they are being launched under Python 3 and not Python 2.  See the [Python 3.1 library reference](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tk.html).